# Load nested data in a React components using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

I have a question. i have a redux store where i have some data like this:

```
team : {
 name: "team name" 
 id: 2,
 players : [ 1, 3, 4, 5 ]
}
```

The players list refers to ids in my database backend.

Then i have a TeamComponent where i need to show the name and the players, for the players i have another component, in that component i want to iterate the players and show the player name, photo age etc.

But i don't know how to pass data to that component because i just have the ids ( 1,2,3,4), should i make an ajax request and then render the child component? but where should i store that data? because i want to keep my store as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you already have the player's info on your store?

Comment: Don't keep player data in global state if you don't need to access it from anywhere else other than your player component. In that case pass player id as props to player component and make ajax request (assuming you don't have player data) at `componentDidMount`. Once request completes update player component's state.

Answer (score 0):

You should be good with these steps:

1. Assuming you have some kind of REST API and [fetching logic](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) – **Request data from top component** with players as related resource.
2. **[Add received data to the state tree](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#handling-actions)**. You should have `teams` and `players` reducers separately.
3. **[Map state to props inside components](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)** and render necessary data.